# A triangle inside an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

> $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle of side $1$.  $ \triangle BDC$  is an isosceles triangle with $D$ opposite to $A$ and $DB = DC$ and $\angle BDC = 120^\circ$.  If points $M$ and $N$ are on $AB$ and $AC$, respectively,  such that $\angle MDN = 60^\circ$, find the perimeter of $\triangle AMN$.

My answer comes out to be $1$ by taking the points $M$ and $N$ in such a way that the quadrilateral $AMDN$ becomes a rhombus. This is all I could do and please help in out extending the result of the perimeter (if correct) to all points $M$ and $N$ in general.

[Question is from the Facebook page created by my teacher](https://www.facebook.com/Mathematics-Gems-by-Ajay-Lakhina-603105973366261/)

Comment: because there are no other restrictions for $M$ and $N$, the perimeter does not depend on their location. However, I am getting $2$ as the perimeter of $\triangle{AMN}$

Comment: Can you share your solution? I rechecked and I am still getting 3/2√3.

Comment: @Vasya It would be really helpful if you could share your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Triangle ABC]

I used the same idea as you, let put $M$ and $N$ in such a way that $AMDN$ is rhombus. Let $E$ be midpoint of $BC$, then $DC=\frac{CE}{\cos 30°}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Notice that $m\angle{NCD}=90°$ then $DN=\frac{DC}{\cos 30°}=\frac{2}{3}$. But $DN=MN=AM=AN$ so perimeter of $\triangle{AMN}=3\cdot \frac{2}{3}=2$

Answer (score 2):

Like Vasya  and Qurultay in the comments, I too get 2.

To find the length of $BD$, let $K$ be a perpendicular bisector of $BC$, which also bisects $\angle BDC$, thus we have a right triangle $\triangle BKD$. Thus:
$$\sin 60^\circ=\frac{0.5}{BD}\Rightarrow BD=\frac{0.5}{\sin 60^\circ}$$

Note that $\angle MBD $ is a right angle${}^{\color{red}{2}}$. We know that $\angle MDB$ is $30^\circ {}^{\color{red}{1}}$. To find $MD$:
$$\cos30^\circ=\frac{BD}{MD}\Rightarrow MD=\frac{BD}{\cos30^\circ}=\frac{0.5}{\cos30^\circ\sin60^\circ}=\frac{0.5}{0.75}=\frac23$$

From this information, we can deduce that $MB=\frac13$ (you can work this out yourself) and thus $AM=\frac23$. We must note that $\triangle MDN$ is isosceles${}^{\color{red}{3}}$, and so is $\triangle AMN$ and thus, knowing $AM$, the perimiter of $\triangle AMN$ is shown as:
$$\mathrm{P}_{\triangle AMN}=3\cdot AM=3\cdot\frac23=2$$

---

${}^{\color{red}{1}}$If $KD$ bisects $BDC$, then $\angle KDB=60^\circ$ and $\angle KMD=30^\circ$ which leaves $\angle MDB=30^\circ$

${}^{\color{red}{2}}$ *see comments*.

${}^{\color{red}{3}}$ Since $MD=AM=\frac23$ and $\angle MAN=\angle MDN=60^\circ$, though I argue there could be a more rigorous proof than this.

Comment: $\angle MBD$ is not a right angle!! $\angle MDB$ is. Then the answer is coming out to be 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, that means $\angle \hat{ABC}$ is $60^\circ$. If $D$ is opposite of $A$ then $\triangle BDC$ must be isosceles, and thus $\angle CBD=30^\circ$ (because the angles of the bases of an isosceles triangle is equal). And thus $$\angle MBD = \angle ABC+\angle CBD=60^\circ+30^\circ=90^\circ\\\mathrm{Q.E.D}$$

Comment: Sorry John! I understood my stupid mistake from Vasya's diagram. Thanks!!

Comment: It's okay. You can look at [this](https://ggbm.at/U85zrdTM) for a more accurate representation

Comment: Thank you John! P.S: I love this forum and the members of the community!